# How to pass [FromBody] parameter in Web API using ExtJS AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, extjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new in ASP.NET Core Web API, I have tried to pass [FromData] through `ExtJS` AJAX call, but it's not working.

**Controller Method:**

This method I need to call through `ExtJS` ajax call:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/values/AddEmployee")]
public int AddEmployee([FromBody] Employee employee)
{
        return objemployee.AddEmployee(employee);
}
```

**Employee Model:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  


    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

**`ExtJS` Ajax Call:**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "http://localhost:1452/api/values/AddEmployee",
        async: false,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept': '*/*' },
        jsonData: {
            employee: {
                EmployeeId: 0,
                Name: empName,
                Gender: "Male",
                Department: empDep,
                City: empCity
            }
        },
        success: function (data) {
            me.down('#grdCaseList').getStore().reload();
        },
        failure: function () {

        }
    });
```

But this AJAX call is not working, is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Have you looked at FromForm instead of FromBody?

Comment: For future reference you should avoid simply saying that code is "not working". It's helpful, indeed essential, to describe in what way. e.g. Which HTTP status do you receive in response, if any? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing valid JSON via the `jsonData` parameter. You need to serialise your JSON object in order to format the request correctly. Try something like:

```
var employee = {
            EmployeeId: 0,
            Name: empName,
            Gender: "Male",
            Department: empDep,
            City: empCity
        };

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "http://localhost:1452/api/values/AddEmployee",
        async: false,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept': '*/*' },
        jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(employee),
        success: function (data) {
            me.down('#grdCaseList').getStore().reload();
        },
        failure: function () {

        }
    });
```

If you want to pass the object directly then you might try (jsonData takes a String or Object):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "http://localhost:1452/api/values/AddEmployee",
        async: false,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept': '*/*' },
        jsonData: {
                "EmployeeId": 0,
                "Name": empName,
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Department": empDep,
                "City": empCity
            },
        success: function (data) {
            me.down('#grdCaseList').getStore().reload();
        },
        failure: function () {

        }
    });
```